# If a flagged post is deleted by the user himself, how can reviewers/moderators see it?

Tags: support, review, flags, deleted-answers

I had flagged a spam-like answer with type ***Other*** (which allows you enter some detailed description) in SO, and it appeared with an `active` tag in my profile. https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/2995038

Few minutes later, I founded the flagged answer deleted (perhaps by the user himself) and I couldn't view it anymore but in my profile the `active` tag was still there. I wonder how reviewer/moderator can see it. If they were unable to see it, would my flag become something like a **"dangling pointer"** ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can see it because we can see all posts, including deleted ones. Self-deletion does not remove flags like Spam or "Other", so someone can't just 'clean up' after themselves quickly. The flag still shows up in our moderator tools.

The flag type you entered does not itself kick up a review task; it is purely a diamond moderator flag. Any review task associated with a deleted post is no longer available, though.

(Just for the record for other readers: The flag the OP above put in was an "Other", not a Spam flag.)